# How is a mathematical operation performed in PHP?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

How is a mathematical operation performed in PHP with values received from "number1" and "number2" The result is shown in "result" ?

```
<div class="row">
<form class="form " action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<form class="form1">
<div class="form-group text-right font-12">
<label for="number">number 1</label>
<input type="number" name="number1" value="" class="form-control" placeholder="number1">
</div>
</form>
<form class="form1">
<div class="form-group text-right font-12">
<label for="number">number 2</label>
<input type="number" name="number2" value="" class="form-control" placeholder="number2">
</div>
</form>
<form class="form1">
<div class="form-group text-right font-12">
<label for="number">The result here</label>
<input type="number" value="" class="form-control" disabled="disabled">
</div>
</form>
<button class="btn btn-info font-12 " type="submit" name="save" value="Show Result">save</button>
</form>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

First of all you don't need nested `form`s to make the UI.

I will write a simple example that you can change to match your UI needs.

```php
<?php

  $a = $_GET['number1'];
  $b = $_GET['number2'];

  $result = NULL;
  if (isset($a) && isset($b)) {
    $result = $a + $b;
  }

?>

<form action="?" method="GET">
  <input name="number1" value="" />
  <input name="number2" value="" />
  <input value="<?= $result ?>" disabled />
  <button type="submit">Show Result</button>
</form>
```

Comment: In OP example... `method = "post"` use `$_POST` instead of `$_GET` -> `$a = $_POST['number1'];` this example does use `method="get"`, however, keep in mind the difference between method `get` and `post`. `Get` places `key`/`value` pairs in URL, `Post` is stored in the request body of the HTTP request.

Comment: @dalelandry why should he use POST ? I think GET is more suitable for this case.

Answer (score 1):

Can you be more specific next time? I think your question is about how to handle such a form in PHP. Just first read some tutorials about it. A great website is w3schools.com. Here is one about form handling: https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_forms.asp

Comment: Thank you for helping and sharing the link